# Адаптивное позиционирование элементов в круг

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно, чтобы одинаковые элементы html выстроились в круг(в центре еще один элемент) При этом также нужно учесть то, чтобы при различных разрешениях экрана они не превращались в эллипс, а всегда оставались кругом. Осложняется эта задача тем, что обязательна аналогичная адаптивность на мобильных устройствах.

```
    <div class="content mh20 sans-serif">
        <div class="circle circle__main">
            <div class="circle__inv">
                <span class="circle__text"> Выберите интересующую тему </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle__inv">
                <span class="circle__text">Что-то</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

И css

```
.circle {
width:  10%;
background: #900C3F;
border-radius:  50%;
text-align: center;
font-size:  18px;
margin: 0 auto;
cursor: pointer;
transition: 1s ease-in;
overflow:   hidden;
position:   absolute;
}
.circle:hover {
background: #0C905D;
}
.circle__main {
width:  20%;
position:   static;
}
.circle__inv {
width:  100%;
height: 100%;
padding-top:    50%;
}
.circle__text {
transform:  translateY(-50%);
display:    inline-block;
}
```

Comment: http://pcvector.net/scripts/menu_and_navigation/73-krugovoe-menyu.html  вот оно

Comment: Тааак, вроде бы не канает, это статика((( Или я чего-то не понял?

Comment: любую статику надо программировать , любое меню надо выводить из базы данных , но в этом не было вопроса - а вот был как такое реализовать - вот и привёл пример с помощью человека не с этого проекта , он мне показал то что вам надо , вот вам и основа

Comment: Я вообще про фронтенд дакак бы. Это не адаптивная верстка круга меню как я понял)))

Comment: если вам надо что бы это было адаптивно , то платите деньги и вам сделают , я могу например - но на халяву даже стараться не буду , если так лёгенькие примеры , а на счёт адаптивной вёрстки - вы же понимаете что на мобилке этого круга не должно быть ?

Comment: Да, я не знаю как воплотить это в реальность, поэтому спрашиваю на различных ресурсах насчет реализации этого. Также я понимаю, что многие просто не захотят терять своё время и деньги на помощь совсем неизвестному человеку, но есть ведь те, кто возможно сталкивался с этим и с радостью ответит. М\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Условимся, что в `css` адаптивный круг и адаптивный квадрат одно и тоже, т.к. `border-radius` это лишь псевдо круг.

### Решение:

**1** Для решения нам понадобится два родительских контейнера(для задания адаптивного квадрата, см. 2) и контейнеры-круги.

**2.** Адаптивный квадрат создается с помощью `padding-(top|bottom): 100%;`. Процент в данном случаи берется от **ширины родительского контейнера** (такая вот особенность).

```
.parent {
  width: 100px;
}
.child {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%; // размер .child будет 100px на 100px
}
```

**3.** Центральный круг можно позиционировать многими способами, я предпочитаю через `absolute`

```
.circle_main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  margin: auto; //фокус именно в margin: auto;
  width: 30%; //к примеру
  height: 30%; //к примеру
}
```

**4.** Для честного позиционирования, придется использовать js, что бы правильно рассчитать координаты внут. кругов.

[Пример решения (с комментариями)](http://codepen.io/olegatro/pen/jWZrgm)

1. Советую изменить расположение так, что бы круг был слева или справа (удобнее изменять ширину окна)
2. Кол-во кругов можно изменять на произвольное кол-во (см. блок `html`)
3. Всё сделано в процентах, так что полная адаптивность
4. Самое главное это выбрать размер внут. круга.
5. В примере используются препроцессор(`stylus`) и шаблонизатор(`jade`), если с ними не знакомы, то там есть кнопка `View Compiled`. Тоже самое с `js`.
6. Адаптивный текст реализован с помощью едениц изменерия `vw`, не везде работает, тут лучше протестировать или найти другой способ изменять размер текста (не стал тут заморачиваться особо).